# How to dynamically change the field type of an item in a collection in a symfony form?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

So i have some entities configured and working with Single Table Inheritance. It is a kind of a budget that can be organized in Chapters, subchapters and so on. For the sake of simplicity let's write a pseudocode version of them:

```
BudgetConcept: abstract
--------
title: string
parent: BudgetConcept
```

-

```
BudgetItem: extends BudgetConcept
--------
units: int
measurementUnit: string
```

-

```
Budget: extends BudgetConcept
--------
budgetConcepts: Collection
```

This is similar to a Composite Pattern. A Budget (which is a BudgetGroup) can have an unlimited number of nested Chapters and the chapters can have Items or other chapters inside.

What I want now is to create a form for the Budget that would have a button "Add" next to each chapter that would display a choice between Chapter and Item.

If the user selects Item, it should show the BudgetItemType fields, and if the user selects Chapter it should show the BudgetGroupType fields

Following for example this docs for embedding collections: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype,

I find that you have to declare an entry_type like:

```
    'entry_type' => BudgetConcept::class,
```

But BudgetConcept is an abstract class and doesn't have a Form Type associated to it. I need a way to either dynamically change the entry_type of an element of the collection on user input or to change to a different workflow I didn't think about.

For reference, I've been trying this without success:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data

Comment: I would suggest to build a generic form containing every single fields that you need (don't map it to any entities). Then you could use js/jquery to show/hide conditionally the fields following your logic. Finally you could use form events in the backend and create the right objects based on what you received.

Comment: I thought something along the lines. Do you have any example of this to share? Can I create the objects inside the form events?